# Get parent name in child record in IN() from same table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
tax_id    tax_name          parent_tax_id
1         Sales Tax         0
2         Lodging Tax       0
3.        Resort Tax        1
4.        Hospitality Tax   2

Select tax_name, tax_id from taxes WHERE tax_id IN (3,4).
```

This above query will get me two rows of id 3 & 4, I need to get tax_name of their parent in same row:

```
SELECT tax_name, tax_id, 
(SELECT tax_name FROM taxes ....) as parent_tax_name 
from taxes WHERE tax_id IN (3,4)
```

and I need to use IN() only, please let me know the way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use a join with itself. LEFT JOIN because not every row seems to have a parent

```
SELECT 
  taxes.tax_name, 
  taxes.tax_id, 
  parent.tax_name AS parent_tax_name 
FROM
  taxes LEFT JOIN taxes AS parent ON taxes.parent_tax_id = parent.tax_id
WHERE 
  taxes.tax_id IN (3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use join query like below,

```
Select t.tax_name, t.tax_id, tt.tax_name as parent_tax from taxes as t left join taxes as tt on (t.parent_tax_id = tt.tax_id) WHERE t.tax_id IN (3,4)
```

parent_tax will be the tax_name for the parent row